# can't open sharepoint site collection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, dns

I have sharepoint foundation 2010 installed on WS 2008 R2 and the AD + SQL + SP intalled on the same server just for testing with IP 10.10.10.10

I create a web application and after that I create a site collection inside that web apllication (http://intranet.contoso.com) and the administrator is sp_admin 
and I create a forwaord lookup zone HOST with same IP above
after that when I try to open the new site collection I got a credential login window I entered the (sp_admin) account and press enter the same window show again after three times it disappear and open empty web-site

where is my mistake, please??

Answer (score 0):

You should have alternate mappings set correctly to be able to use http://intranet.contoso.com address. And you should also have the http://intranet.contoso.com in Trusted sites list within IE as normally IE does not sends your credentials to internet sites. Using full address is always handled as access to internet site by IE.

Comment: i solve this issue by disableloopbackcheck in regedit